# OpenERP module google_earth address field

Tags: python, odoo

I want to use openerp google_earth module. I successfully installed it and generated kml file with partners information. I want to put all partners on google map to see where they are on map, but the problem is that for some reason, kml file only gets country and city from openerp database (res.partners object).

Field street for some reason is not being added into field address (the one that appears on kml file) as it should be like this:

```
address=city+country+street
```

But it is like this:

```
address=city+country
```

I even tried to modify google_earth.py file like this (I added street field where address field is generated at res_partner class):

```
if add.street:
    address += ',  '
    address += tools.ustr(add.street)
```

But nothing changed. So is it possible to make it add street field too? Because without that, such module is really useless.

Answer (score 0):

Similar code is found in Google_map module, which will help you how to use the whole address earch on the map. Check [this url](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.0/view/head:/google_map/wizard/google_map_launch.py#L28)

Comment: It seems my added code is working and it adds street info to address field. But the problem is that it doesn't change coordinates where that partner should be. So adding street field into address doesn't do much.. 
Maybe someone knows how to change directions according not only to country and city, but also street?..

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the address after the country? Google might expect the address to come before the city and country. The code that [firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648599/4794) linked to put the address first.

Comment: Tried to put street first, but same thing. google_earth actually is a bit different than google_maps